# getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView() is not capturing on screen keyboard, alerts with in the app and progressdialog during network calls

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, screenshot

My application needs to capture the on-screen with soft keyboard. But the following line is not capturing them.

```
View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Comment: The soft keyboard has its own window. To my knowledge you cannot get that.

Comment: **keyboard** is not included in the `getRootView`.

Comment: Is there any other go to get it..?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known problem while capturing the screen.
Actually this also cannot be called as an issue as this is the default behavior of the Android view hierarchy. I am trying to explain it in a simple language:

The view which you are trying to capture using the Drawing cache, has a separate window layer of it's own.
AlertDialog,Dialog,Keyboard,Progressdialog etc. has it's own separate decorview window which is different from your view's window hierarchy.
You can definitely see this difference as it has a different Z-index and it floats above the view of your activity.

```
View.getDrawingCache()
```

method only captures the views that are in the scope of the View of your activity, and in this case, the dialog,keyboard etc are placed above the view and not in the scope of the view.
So it doesn't get captured as a bitmap while using this method.

I hope this helps you understand that this is not an issue but a limitation that we cannot capture the dialog and floating windows using Drawing cache.
If there are any methods to do it, I would also like to know about that.

Thanks.

Comment: So How could someOne take screen of the whole screen. not talking about activity or application.Saying the root of all the apps.

Comment: That can achieve on lolipop and above device only

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/projection/MediaProjectionDemo.java